# Tkinter label round corner

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, android-music-player

how can I rounded corner of border labels?
Please explain simply, i read some topics and question and answers but I did not understand any
sorry for bad english:D

in this part

```
tk.Label(root, text="List of songs",fg = "#30414B", font = ("Old Letterhand",23)).pack()
```

Comment: I believe that is not possible.

Comment: You can use `Canvas` with a round-corners rectangle and text items to simulate a round-corners label.

Comment: You can use an image for the background to draw the rounded corners, using the options `image=<border image>` and `compound="center"`.